# (Done) Re-Open: question on looking for out of state job and changing careers

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[I've been looking for an out-of-state job for 6 months now, what else could I do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120084/ive-been-looking-for-an-out-of-state-job-for-6-months-now-what-else-could-i-do)

^ this question was closed for "specific choice", however I think the core of the question was actually about looking for suggestions for other strategies/tactics to try in the OP's search (rather than a "should I do this or not?" question) so I've done an edit to try and make that clearer and IMO it is now answerable.

Comment: It was a good edit. I voted to re-open.

Comment: I have no idea why it was put on hold in the first place.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere me neither.. as my ever cryptic mother would say "a blind man on a galloping horse could see what that question was about!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cast the fifth reopen vote just now.

Comment: Much obliged! :)